# What is the best way to integrate ExpressionEngine members with MailChimp?

Tags: expressionengine, subscription, newsletter, mailchimp

I am developing a site that uses [FreeMember](http://github.com/expressodev/freemember) to handle user sign-up, login and profile updating. We want to offer a way for users to sign up for the newsletter when creating an account as well as the option to (un)subscribe by updating their EE profile.

Is there an add-on that handles this functionality? I have tried to set up [MailChimp Subscribe](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/sl-mailchimp-subscribe) but it doesn't allow updating subscriptions with FreeMember.

Any advice is welcome.

Comment: Are you sure Freemember doesn't work with Mailchimp Subscribe? It should work at least for registrations..

Comment: It does work with registrations, however it does not work when the user updates their profile.

Comment: It would probably be a piece of cake to add Freemember support to Mailchimp Subscribe (for profile updates), if that's helpful to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Robon Sobral has a [fork of FreeMember](https://github.com/robsonsobral/freemember) that adds support for updating subscriptions when a user updates their profile. This patch solved my issues.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look over at Devot-ee http://devot-ee.com/search/results?keywords=mailchimp&collection=addons&addon_version_support=ee2 there are several options listed.

Stephen Lewis recently open-sourced his add-ons so his mailchimp add-on can be found on github here https://github.com/experience/mailchimp_subscribe.ee_addon

Comment: I am aware of Devot:ee and I mentioned in my question that I was having issues with Stephen Lewis' MailChimp Subscribe.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at our latest add-on Postmaster. It does a lot more than MC integration. It focusses on providing 1 add-on for all email services. You can create email campaigns just by creating new channel entries. You can create any number of template and variations to have really complex and dynamic interactions. It works with Safecracker and regular Publish entries.

But speaking directly to MC integration, it also has standalone subscribe tags (both a tag and standalone form). You can get any list of subscribers, and even unsubscribe with tags and a standalone form. All of this integration works with both MC and CampaignMonitor with the same tags (same syntax).

https://objectivehtml.com/articles/postmaster-the-definitive-email-solution-for-expressionengine

The next version (v1.2) is finished and currently in beta, which includes support for CartThrob and any other EE hook. For example, you can now send all systems emails with Mandrill or SendGrid. We had a lot of clients complain their receipts (sent from EE using CartThrob) went to spam or they were never received. We solved this problem with Postmaster by redirecting those emails to a proper service (SendGrid in our case) which has a reliable delivery system with reporting and analytics. You can even do things like send an email when a specific member group logs into the site.

We took a radically different approach than all the other add-ons and tried to provide a much more abstract utility that is capable of solving a lot of complex problems. I would have happy to answer any specific questions directly (just use the contact form on my site).

Comment: Sounds interesting, I found a solution but I'll have to check it out next time project I work on.